# PowerShell to update XML element (inner text)

Tags: xml, powershell

Given this XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I would like to change the "v.4.6.1" by "v4.7.1" using PowerShell.

Currently, I load the XML above with this:

```bsh
$content = [xml](Get-Content $path.FullName)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$content.Project.PropertyGroup.TargetFrameworkVersion = 'v4.7.1'
```

This relies on PowerShell conveniently exposing an XML document's DOM by decorating the `[System.Xml.XmlNode]` instances that make up the object hierarchy with *properties* that reflect a node's XML attributes and child elements, which enables regular dot notation.

Comment: Would this work if the .xml file were "large?" Perhaps 500 GiB? More than most machines have physical memory. Will it efficiently page?

Comment: @lit: It probably doesn't scale well. As a rule of thumb, the convenience that PowerShell offers comes at a cost: typically, performance-wise (execution speed); while the pipeline offers streaming, one-by-one processing, it can't be leveraged here; for huge files that don't fit into memory, you'll need a streaming parser such as `[XmlReader]`(https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader?view=netframework-4.7.2) - you can probably make that work in PowerShell, though I haven't tried. It sounds like an interesting topic to explore, so I encourage you to ask a new question.